# sed - replace match containing two wildcards

Tags: sed

I'm having trouble trying to replace a match. My example file:

`cat ntpd`:

```
OPTIONS="-g"
OPTIONS="-u ntg:ntp -p /var/run/ntpd.pid -g"
OPTIONS="-u root:root -p /var/run/ntpd.pid -g"
OPTIONS="-u root:root"
OPTIONS="-u"
```

I'd like to replace any occurrence of "`-u *:*`" with "`-u ntp:ntp`"

I've tried variants of:

```
sed 's/-u\ \(.*\)\:\(.*\)/-u ntp:ntp/g' ntpd
```

but that's giving me results in which everything after the replacement string is being lost:

```
OPTIONS="-g"
OPTIONS="-u ntp:ntp
OPTIONS="-u ntp:ntp
OPTIONS="-u ntp:ntp
OPTIONS="-u"
```

....if I add a space after the second wildcard `(.*\)` like `sed 's/-u\ \(.*\)\:\(.*\) /-u ntp:ntp/g' ntpd` that strangely results in:

```
OPTIONS="-g"
OPTIONS="-u ntp:ntp-g"
OPTIONS="-u ntp:ntp-g"
OPTIONS="-u root:root"
OPTIONS="-u"
```

...where a line in which the pattern match no longer matches because it isn't trailed by a space no longer gets replaced (not good), and the line containing a space and more text after is finding the `-g` as the only remaining text, but I'd assume it would have left all `-p /var/run/ntpd.pid -g` trailing text.

Any `sed` experts out there, any/all guidance is appreciated. My desired results would be:

```
OPTIONS="-g"
OPTIONS="-u ntp:ntp -p /var/run/ntpd.pid -g"
OPTIONS="-u ntp:ntp -p /var/run/ntpd.pid -g"
OPTIONS="-u ntp:ntp"
OPTIONS="-u"
```

Comment: `.*` is too unspecific. It matches literally everything. Maybe something like `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*` instead?

Comment: @melpomene good deal, this modifaction does appear to work: `sed 's/-u\ \(.*\)\:[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*/-u ntp:ntp/g' ntpd` Thanks! Post as an answer and I'll accept, looks good to me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All proposed answers work to a degree, but both have problems (a trailing `"` is wrongly dropped).

```
OPTIONS="-g"
OPTIONS="-u ntp:ntp -p /var/run/ntpd.pid -g"
OPTIONS="-u ntp:ntp -p /var/run/ntpd.pid -g"
OPTIONS="-u ntp:ntp
OPTIONS="-u"
```

Whereas, the comment provided answer by @melpomene was the first response and ultimate solution, for this case at least.

Using `sed 's/-u\ [a-zA-Z0-9_-]*:[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*/-u ntp:ntp/g' ntpd`

results in the much desired:

```
OPTIONS="-g"
OPTIONS="-u ntp:ntp -p /var/run/ntpd.pid -g"
OPTIONS="-u ntp:ntp -p /var/run/ntpd.pid -g"
OPTIONS="-u ntp:ntp"
OPTIONS="-u"
```

Answer (score 1):

This command should do it:

```
sed 's/-u\( [^:]\{1,\}:[^ ]\{1,\}\)/-u ntp:ntp/' file
```

Output:

```
OPTIONS="-g"
OPTIONS="-u ntp:ntp -p /var/run/ntpd.pid -g"
OPTIONS="-u ntp:ntp -p /var/run/ntpd.pid -g"
OPTIONS="-u"
```

Btw, using *extended posix regular expressions* with `-r` the command becomes a bit more readable:

```
sed -r 's/-u( [^:]{1,}:[^ ]{1,})/-u ntp:ntp/' file
```

Comment: This works better than what I had in the OP. But it's actually adding ` ntp:ntp ` after the `-u` which doesn't contain any `*:*` following it. I only want to replace occurrences that have an existing `user:group` only.

Comment: Ah ok. I misunderstood that requirement. I just need to replace the `*` quantifier in that case. second...

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/-u\s\S+:\S+/-u ntp:ntp/' file
```

Using `\s` to represent a space and `\S` to represent a non-space and the qualifier `+` to represent one or more of the preceeding character or class of characters, the regexp matches a `-u` followed by a single space, followed by one or more non-spaces, followed by a `:`, followed by one or more non-spaces.